# Can't Submit apps to App Store, can't select any app

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am trying to submit my app to the app store and when I archive it and enter my iTunesConnect email and password it says in application "Not Value". My app is currently "Waiting For Upload".

The weird part is that if I give a bad password it saysthe same thing. App: "Not Value", and I've checked the email and password and they are correct.

What can I do? I need to submit today :S

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

Just download and reinstall the Xcode and you will get all the certified right.

Just archive it and you will submit. This is because Application Loader was corrupted [I don't know why].

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I submit an app to the App Store:

1. Open the app in Xcode.
2. Go to the Product menu item and select Archive.
3. Open the Xcode Organizer.
4. Select Archives.
5. Select the App and version number you want to submit.
6. Press submit.
7. Fill in your iTunes Connect username and password.
8. Select the correct provisioning profile.
9. Fix any errors or warnings and repeat the process.
10. Once this is completed, you should see a message telling you that your app has been received and is now waiting to be reviewed.

Comment: Yes but when you select the correct provisioning profile. You also select the app that you got in iTunes connect in there it said. No Value :S. I already restart the laptop, erase and get all certifies :S

Comment: Try recreating your self-signed certificate. I had trouble with that a while ago.